# apk not getting installed on phone while on blue stack it runs fine

Tags: android-studio, webview, package, installation, build.gradle

I had to change my apk name from debug-apk to a new on so I tried to change the build.gradle code,  but it didn't work so I reversed everything. 
But now the apk file that is generated runs fine in blue stack 
But it says "Package installer stopped " when I try to install it on my phone.

I don't understand wth has happened.

And also when I created a new project and copied all the files as they were except the gradle file , the same problem occurs. 
The apk runs on blue stack,  but not on my phone.

I tried it on different phone too.

I think there's a problem with my Android studio.

Please help.

Ps - before changing the build.gradle code the apk was working fine on my phone too

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rupam.univ"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

Comment: dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    }